# Java - How to access Enum Class and Enum objects via strings?

Tags: java, enums

So I have a java class with multiple Enums

```
public class Enumerations {
    public enum Days {
        Monday("MON")
        Tuesday("Tue")

        string value;
        private Days(String value){
            this.value = value
        }
        public string getValue(){
            return this.value;
        }
    }
    public enum Months{
        January("JAN")
        APRIL("APR")

        string value;
        private Months(String value){
            this.value = value
        }
        public string getValue(){
            return this.value;
        }
    }
}
```

And now I have another class in which I want to access the enum class via a string as i cannot instantiate the enum directly as i am unaware of the enum that is to be used and access enum values from a variable string(unaware of this as well).

```
class EnumParser{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        String enum = "Days";     //Will get this value from external source so its variable(Can be months or days)
        String value = "Monday"   //This is going to variable as well with value unknown.
    }
}
```

So how do i get output as "MON" here using string variables

```
Enumerations.{{Days}}.{{Monday}}.getValue();
```

edited the question for a clearer view, both Days ans Monday are variables.

Comment: Your problem statement is not clear.

Comment: possible is: Days.valueOf("Monday").getValue(); (solves 1/2  of your question)

Comment: @RavindraRanwala Enum name and enum value are variables(not pre defined) hence need a java statement to get output using the string variables for enum name and enum value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `if-else` or `switch` statements to determine which enum to use, and then use `valueOf()`:

```
String e = "Days";
String value = "Monday";

if (e.equalsIgnoreCase(Enumerations.Days.class.getSimpleName())) {
    System.out.println(Enumerations.Days.valueOf(value).getValue());
} else if (e.equalsIgnoreCase(Enumerations.Months.class.getSimpleName())) {
    System.out.println(Enumerations.Months.valueOf(value).getValue());
} else {
    System.out.println("Could not find enum");
}
```

Output:

```
MON
```

**Update** based on comment that you might have 200+ enums:

You can use reflection like so:

```
String e = "Days";
String value = "Monday";

String res = Arrays.stream(Enumerations.class.getDeclaredClasses())
        .filter(c -> c.getSimpleName().equalsIgnoreCase(e))
        .findFirst()
        .map(c -> {
            String result = null;
            try {
                Object o = c.getMethod("valueOf", String.class).invoke(null, value);
                result = (String) o.getClass().getMethod("getValue").invoke(o);
            } catch (IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException | NoSuchMethodException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            return result;
        }).orElse("Could not find");
System.out.println(res); //prints MON
```

Comment: But what if I have 200+ enums. any other solution instead of switch case, in which I'll be able to use the enum directly

Answer (score 0):

Make a static method which retrieves the appropriate enum value for you:

```
//inside Days, skips some excess array creation
private static final Days[] VALUES = Days.values();

public static Days getDay(String day) {
    return Arrays.stream(VALUES)
        .filter(d -> d.value.equalsIgnoreCase(day))
        .findAny(); //Optional<Days>
        //can use #orElse/#orElseThrow to decide behavior for a mismatch
}
```

Then it's a matter of simply getting the enum directly:

```
Days monday = Days.getDay("MON");
```

You can make multiple methods which filter around these inputs, if you like. Even further if you really want to get crazy, you can pass a `Predicate<Days>` (or whichever enum) and filter that way:

```
public static Days getDay(Predicate<Days> filter) {
    return Arrays.stream(VALUES)
        .filter(filter)
        //In this case I'm returning null for no match
        .findAny().orElse(null);
}
```

Then:

```
Days monday = Days.getDay(d -> d.getValue().equalsIgnoreCase("MON"));
```

Now in the strict case of `Monday`, you can use `Days#valueOf`, but this will throw an error if there is no enum constant for the string you search for.

```
Days monday = Days.valueOf("Monday"); //okay
//all of these below would throw an error
monday = Days.valueOf("monday");
monday = Days.valueOf("MONDAY");
monday = Days.valueOf("not even close to monday");
```

I would also adhere to conventions for enums here (all caps letters and underscores for spacing, so `MONDAY`).

Lastly, if this isn't just an example problem and you're actually working with days/calendar variables etc, you have the `DayOfWeek` and `Month` enums already available in the default jdk.

Answer (score 0):

Try reflection way;

```
package com.company;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;

class Enumerations {
    public enum Days {
        Monday("MON"),
        Tuesday("Tue");

        String value;
        Days(String value){
            this.value = value;
        }
        public String getValue(){
            return this.value;
        }
    }
    public enum Months{
        January("JAN"),
        APRIL("APR");

        String value;
        Months(String value){
            this.value = value;
        }
        public String getValue(){
            return this.value;
        }
        }
}
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // know the specific class name
        System.out.println(Enumerations.Months.class);
        String enumName = "Days";
        String value = "Monday";
        // get the class by class name
        Class c = Class.forName("com.company.Enumerations$" + enumName);
        // new the object by value
        Object o = Enum.valueOf(c, value);
        // get the method by name
        Method method = c.getMethod("getValue");
        // invoke the method
        System.out.println(method.invoke(o));
    }
}
```